# confusion with params passing and routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having association 
group has_many events

I am having this method in show group view

```
= link_to 'Create Event', new_event_path(@group)
```

my new event method

```
  def new     
     @event = Event.new(city: current_user.profile.city, group_id: params[:id])
  end
```

It is showing unknown url
 localhost:3000/events/new.17

also group_id: params[:id] is not working

as i m new to ror please tell me reason 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify parent resource therefore you can't use it as parameter in your `new_event_path` URL helper and generate path like '/parent_resource/:parent_resource_id/events/new'. So, in you case just use any URL parameter i.e. `group_id`:

```
= link_to 'Create Event', new_event_path(group_id: @group)
```

it will generate URL: `/events/new?group_id=17`

In this case the action will use `group_id` parameter:

```
def new     
   @event = Event.new(city: current_user.profile.city, group_id: params[:group_id])
end
```